# iOS subscription DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS notification: latest_expired_receipt vs latest_receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app-subscription

I am working on adding subscription to my iOS app and I came across some very annoying inconsistencies:

My server is listening for the `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` notification from Apple:

```
{
    "auto_renew_status_change_date": "2019-06-05 13:42:43 Etc/GMT",
    "environment": "Sandbox",
    "auto_renew_status": "false",
    "auto_renew_status_change_date_pst": "2019-06-05 06:42:43 America/Los_Angeles",
    "latest_expired_receipt": "ewoJIn...",
    "latest_expired_receipt_info": ⊖{
        "original_transaction_id": "10000001010101010",
        "expires_date_formatted": "2019-06-05 13:43:13 Etc/GMT",
        ...
    },
    "password": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "auto_renew_status_change_date_ms": "1559742163000",
    "auto_renew_product_id": "com.my.product",
    "notification_type": "DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS"
}
```

During my tests the notification contained in almost all cases a `latest_expired_receipt` and a `latest_expired_receipt_info`.

**BUT** some message contained `latest_receipt` and a `latest_receipt_info` instead. Beside this difference the structure of the messages was identical (`"auto_renew_status": "false"`, `auto_renew_status_change_date` **before** the `expires_date_formatted`, etc.)

**Does Apple change the structure randomly to make implementing subscription even more enjoyable or is there any logic on when which structure is used?**

Of course I can simply adapt my server code to check if `latest_receipt` **OR** `latest_expired_receipt` is available but this would be a quick and dirty solution. I would prefer to understand when to expect which content/structure...

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? if yes, please share

Comment: Not really. My solution is to check for both fields and use the one which is available. I found no information on when which field is used but it seems the they are not used both at the same time...

Answer (score 3):

Apple constantly make developer's life harder.

As stated in App Store Server Notifications documentation, top-level objects *latest_receipt, latest_receipt_info, latest_expired_receipt, and latest_expired_receipt_info* are scheduled for deprecation. This could be the reason for the notification to behave differently.

You should update your code to rely on ***latest_receipt*** & ***latest_receipt_info*** in **unified_receipt** object instead.
[image: test]
Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody

Comment: Thanks for this important hin! Always fun to work with Apple APIs and services...... However, so far I not could find a `unified_receipt` field in any received transactions?! It seems that one has to make a good guess how a receipt should look like, and which field could have which meaning...

Answer (score 0):

If the order is expired when autorenew status is changes you are going to get latest_expired_receipt_info and latest_expired_receipt ( this cases include orders that are in billing retry and app store could not renew them during billing retry period, or the order was refunded), for other cases when subscription is still valid you will get latest_receipt  and latest_receipt_info